# Call to a member function replicate() on null (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, duplicates

I am working on laravel 5.3 and i have to store a duplicate row from table here is my function and i am getting following error
**Call to a member function replicate() on null**
 please help me to fix it 
function

```
public function copy($id){

$task = Task::find(1);
$newTask = $task->replicate();
$newTask->save();
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure `$task` has the correct value?

Comment: yes i have define in Task every thing carefully @Sougata Bose

Comment: Well, the error mssage says `$task` is null. There is most likely no task with that id.

Comment: can you add `dd($task)` and show the output?

Comment: yes i try it have null 
i try something different as i passed $id here instead of 1 as $task = Task::find($id);

Its working but its replicate 3 times @Sougata Bose

Answer (score 0):

```

public function copy($id){

```
$task = Task::find(1);
if (null !== $task) {
    $newTask = $task->replicate();
    if (null !== $newTask) {
        $newTask->save();
    }
}
```

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this problem more readable you can use [firstOrFail method of Laravel's Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#retrieving-single-models). If there is no result found with id - 1, the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException` is thrown, which you may catch and proceed further.

The code goes like this:

```
public function copy($id) {
   try {
     $task = Task::firstOrFail(1);
     $newTask = $task->replicate();
     $newTask->save();
   } catch(Exception $e) {
      // If nothing found with that (1) id, then the throws exception is catched here!
   }
}
```